# Provision AppPart/ClientWebPart to SharePoint Page

Tags: app-part

I am facing Issue with provisioning App Part through `Element.xml` while deploying through Visual Studio. It is showing the below error.

> **Web Part Error: The MyFavApp ClientWebPart feature d21cfbef-1576-4db2-bb10-1d9ae83e558a is not installed or is not
>   Active. Correlation ID: adfe0e9d-302e-2000-0d17-77f1f7acfff8.**

Anybody know how to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you troubleshoot what your error show here?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-declaratively-add-app.html, `FeatureId` should be the same as `ProductId` from the appmanifest.

However, I've found that at least on my installation, SharePoint doesn't use the same Guid for the `FeatureId` as it does for the `ProductID` that is specified in the `AppManifest.xml` file.

It seems that typically, for whatever reason, the `FeatureId` is different by one character from the AppManifest `ProductId`.

Running the powershell command:

```
Get-SPFeature -web <site url> | select DisplayName, Id
```

and using the Guid that is *nearly* identical to the `ProductId` as the `FeatureId` seems to work.